# vue3 : how to remove backend.js console message

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, console.log, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 and each time I start the app or refresh the page or run any method , there is a console message from **backend.js** and the console is an object :

```
backend.js:2551 {uid: 0, vnode: {…}, type: {…}, parent: null, appContext: {…}, …}
```

it is very annoying, and I could not able to remove it.

backend.js console message on line no 2551.

[image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely coming from vue devtools (since vue itself doesn't use backend.js)

You could try updating the plugin, which is still in beta, so changes may happen frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Is as simple as right click on the request in the network tab and block the url

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the message and select "hide messages from backend.js"